# problems to retrieve data from hasManyThrough relationship in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, has-many-through

I have 3 tables in my Database:

1. posts contains(`id`, `title`)
2. categories (`id`, `name`),
3. categories_posts (`post_id`, `categories_id`).

I am using *laravel 4.2*. That are my Models:

*Post.php*

```
protected $table = 'posts';
public function categories_posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categories_post', 'post_id');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Categories', 'Categories_post');
}
```

*Categories.php*

```
protected $table = 'categories';

protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];

public function categories_posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Categories_post', 'categories_id');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'Categories_post');
}
```

*Categories.php*

```
protected $table = 'categories_posts';

protected $fillable = ['categories_id', 'post_id'];

public function categories()
{

    return $this->belongsTo('Categories');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Post');
}
```

*PostsController.php*

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('author')->get();
    return View::make('posts.index', (
        'posts' => $posts);
}
```

shortly presents main code
index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td>
   <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
   <td>{{ $post->author->display_name }}</td>
   @foreach ($post->categories->categories_post as $cat)
     <td>{{ $cat->name }}</td><!-- how to get category name associated with posts !>
   @endforeach
   <td>{{ $post->status }}</td>
   <td>{{ $post->comments_count }}</td>
  @endforeach
```

That code returns errors, I don't understand.

So how to get a `category` name, which is related to `posts` by `hasManyThrough` relation.

Suggest me if there is a better way, than make use of the `hasManyThrough` relation.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the hasManyThrough relation. What exactly do you need? Show all Posts in a Category? Show all Categories that a Post belongs to?

Comment: You table doesn't need hasManyThrough relation. It is however a Many To Many relationship, just use belongsToMany relation. View the docs
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: yes i need this "Show all Categories that a Post belongs to" @KaloyanDoichinov

Comment: But how? i followed the doc of laravel...and do the same but i don't know where is my fault, plz use this code and run i use both the way...@SushantAryal